# Determine if $f(x) = \frac{100}{1+2^{-x}}$ is one-to-one

Tags: calculus, inverse, inverse-function

I currently have $$f(x) = \frac{100}{1+2^{-x}}$$ and I'm trying to determine if it is one-to-one. I have looked at the other posts however I'm not sure as to how to deal with the $-x$.

Comment: Did you try graphing the function so you at least have a guess?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  I've edited your question to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make it readable, you may wish to look at the edit history to see how it works here.  Also, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3990639/edit) your question to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: @ElliotG Question also states not allowed to graph it but Ill do it to give myself an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x)=\dfrac{100}{1+2^{-x}}$ then $2^{-x}=\dfrac{100}{f(x)}-1$ so $x=-\log_{2}\dfrac{100}{f(x)}=\log_2 f(x)-\log_2 100$.

$f$ is injective, as if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $x_1=-\log_{2}\dfrac{100}{f(x_1)}=-\log_{2}\dfrac{100}{f(x_1)}=x_2$, because $\log_2$ is injective. Whether $f$ is surjective or not depends on the Range you choose for $f$.

Answer (score 0):

It is because $y=2^{-x}$ is.  An exponential function to any positive base is.  You could take the derivative, and check that it's strictly decreasing.

Also, $y=\dfrac{100}{1+x}$ is one-to-one.  So we have the composition of two one-to-one functions.